# how to get the data of edit text declared in one class in another class

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i m trying to parse the data from a link with gets information about city and state from an edit text i want to get the data of edit text save it in a string and then use that string in another class. i tried my best by creating an object an calling the function but it don't work please someone help me

this is the code for getting the text and returing that string to a function.

```
         public String et(){
    location= et.getText().toString();
    return this.location;
}
```

and this is the other class where i am using this edittext by saving it in a string

```
     public void test(){
    Main mm= new Main();
    location1= mm.et();
    }
```

but it don't work where i am going wrong i don't know.i know its silly question but please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make location as a `static String` and access it in other class using `Class_Name.location`;

```
class myClass {
static String location=null;
 public void et(){
    location= et.getText().toString();
      }
}
```

//Now consider method et was called and location variable have been initialized to some String

```
  class aClass {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println(myClass.location);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just print the results of the first function to a file and then load that file in the second function.